# ng-if to hide all elements in page except 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have several divs on my page which use an ng-if to show. My issue is that certain elements are duplicates.

What I would like to do is use another expression in the ng-if for this example i added below (hideMultiplePost) to hide these duplicate elements and my idea is to identify them by adding a class which uses the post id since the duplicate elements share the same id.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in postList">
    <div class="{{post.id}}" ng-if="post.cat.length > 0 && hideMultiplePost(post.id)">
</div>

<div ng-repeat="post in postListV2">
    <div class="{{post.id}}" ng-if="post.cat.length > 0 && hideMultiplePost(post.id)">
</div>
```

Can someone put me in the right direction in using an expression (hideMultiplePost) where I check for duplicate classes and exclude them from the frontend but leave one them as I don't want to exclude them all.

Comment: Do you need to display the duplicates? Or can you exclude them within the controller directly in the array/object?

Comment: Exclude them but not all. Amended the last paragraph to be clear. Also I dont want to exclude them from the array just from the frontend thats why I decided the best option would be to target classes

Comment: instead of excluding them from the array maybe you can add a flag on each object indicating if it is a duplicate or not. With this way you can have an `ng-if="post.duplicated"` that takes care of hiding the duplicated items

Comment: Thanks Akis but I can't amend the api. The only thing that I can recognise from a post being duplicate is its id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot control the data in, then you can remove dupes using a filter. I have assumed it's an ng-repeat, but you can edit for your own use. More detail in fiddle.

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in data | dedupe:'id'">
      {{item.id}}: {{item.name}}
   </div>
```

Edit:
Concat the two sources (`postList` and `postListV2`) in your controller, and then use the filter to dedupe:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.postList = postList;
    $scope.data = $scope.postList.concat(postListV2)
}
```

More info in the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7736/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the existing 'unique' filter supplied by angular UI.

The unique filter allows you to supply a field in your model that should be unique. I assume that all of your posts have a `id` and that this `id` is unique. You can filter out multiple posts based on this field.

After the applied filter, you can still use your `ng-if` statement to check if the post contains any categories.

Check the snippet for more info on how to use it.

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ui.filters']);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('PostListController', PostListController);

function PostListController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.posts = getPosts();
}


function getPosts() {
  return [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "content": "Post content here"
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="PostListController as vm">
    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | unique:'id'">
        <b>#{{ post.id }} {{ post.title }} </b><br />
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ...so include an entirely extra library for a simple filter?

Comment: Thanks and that would work but I am not being clear apologies. I am getting duplicate ids because I have multiple data and I am combining them together on a single page.

So I have multiple divs each with ng-repeat which call w different apis. since the ids on each api will conflict I want to show only 1 thats why the only way to do the exclusion is by excluding classes unless this info gives you guys a better idea.

Comment: What format is the data, how do you combine them, and how are you displaying it on the page?

Comment: @fraccus: You're right, to include angularUI if it was not yet included it will add too much overhead. But for what I've seen, in many projects it is already included.

Comment: Change the code in the initial post. hope this helps.

Comment: @Jason: Is everything managed by the same controller, or multiple controllers?

Comment: @MenzoWijmenga same controller.

Comment: @Jason Okay, I will update this answer with a additional snippet. One moment.

Comment: @Jason almost finished updating this one. But I see your answer is sufficient. Thanks :)

Comment: @MenzoWijmenga Thanks. Any input you want to give is welcome and will make sure I give credit as I love to learn new things.